# Markov chain and laws of large number

Tags: probability, markov-chains, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_n$ be a (could assume this is homogenous) markov chain on a countable state space $S$, and write $N_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{\{X_k=x\}}$. Let $z\in S$ be a recurrent state, denote by $R_z$ its accessibility equivalence class, and let $\mu_z(y)=\mathbb{E}_zN_{\tau_z}(y)=\mathbb{E}(N_{\tau_z}(y)|X_0=z)$ where $\tau_z=\inf\{k: X_k=z\}$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{N_n(y)}{N_n(z)}=\mu_z(y)$$ holds $\mathbb{P}_x$ a.s for $x,y\in R_z$ where $\mathbb{P}_x(X)=\mathbb{P}(X|X_0=x)$.

Writing $\mu_z$ out, this is similar to Laws of large numbers? But I didn't get very far from it. Any hints, idea? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, if I can simplify the heavy notation here: It looks like $\tau_z$ is intended to be a recurrence time from state $z$ back to state $z$, and $\mu_z(y)$ is the expected number of visits to state $y$ during this recurrence interval.  So, you need to use _renewal theory_ ("limiting averages, ratios of expectations, mean recurrence times"):  For example, by renewal theory we know the limiting fraction of time being in state $y$ is just the ratio of expectations $\mu_z(y)/E[\tau_z]$ (with prob 1). I'm sure you can solve the problem now.